# Get cell address from custom INDEX+MATCH function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this handy custom function

```
Public Function XLOOKUP(lk As Variant, lCol As Range, rCol As Range)

XLOOKUP = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Index(rCol, Application.Match(lk, lCol, 0)), "0")

End Function
```

Is it possible to get cell address of "X" to replace its value, where

```
X = XLOOKUP("text", Sheet1.Range("D1:D300"), Sheet1.Range("E1:E300"))
```

Edit:
Thanks to Scott ...

```
x = XLOOKUP("text", Sheet1.Range("D1:D300"), Sheet1.Range("E1:E300"))
xNew = Sheet1.Range("E1:E300").Cells(Application.Match("text", Sheet1.Range("D1:D300"), 0)).Address(0, 0)
If x = "" Then Sheet1.Range(xNew) = 0
```

Comment: not trough X, as it will be just a value.  You will need to use something like `add = rCol.Cells(Application.Match(lk, lCol, 0),1).Address(0,0)` on a different line.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Can you explain how you intend to use the address?

Comment: What I mean by that is when the cell, which contains the value of `x` is empty, put in that cell a value of `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to return a range and then use that in the sub:

```
Public Function XLOOKUP(lk As Variant, lCol As Range, rCol As Range) As Range

    Dim mtch As Variant
    mtch = Application.Match(lk, lCol, 0)
    
    If IsError(mtch) Then Exit Function
    
    Set XLOOKUP = rCol.Cells(mtch, 1)

End Function
```

```
Sub doThings()
    Dim x As Range
    Set x = XLOOKUP("text", Sheet1.Range("D1:D300"), Sheet1.Range("E1:E300"))
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
        If x.Value = "" Then x = 0
        MsgBox x.value
    Else
        MsgBox "text not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Scott,  I'm gonna use your first proposal. It's a single occurrence, and for now I prefer the simpler solution.

Comment: @Danchev you will find the function above even if you change it back to just returning the value will be much quicker if you are looping than the one you show.  Application.Index is much slower than just using range.Cells.  Just an FYI.

Comment: How to make `If IsError(mtch)` to return value of `0`, not exit the function?

Comment: I am catching that in the sub, the part of `If Not x is Nothing Then`  x will be nothing if nothing is found to match.

Comment: I'm using this function at least 50 times, that's why I want the "no match" situation to be handled at function level and "match + empty value cell" (as I said a single occurrence) in the sub. Gonna try `WorksheetFunction.IfError` with the `Application.Match(lk, lCol, 0)` tomorrow ...